# I cannot log in, and I am said I have 5 failed logins

Tags: users

I've setup a virtual host on one of my machines. The front page shows fine, but the other pages don't. When I put in my login information, and I click the "Log in" button, I get the "page not found" error.

If I go to www.example.com/?q=user, I get that page, but when I try logging in, I see the following error message:

> Sorry, there have been more than 5 failed login attempts for this account. It is temporarily blocked. Try again later or request a new password."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try my solution below.

Comment: I dont think its related to Clean URL as the message implies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quick solution is to login in your database
`mysql -u <username> -p<password>` or `drush sql-cli`

and execute this query

`truncate flood;`

Thats it and you'll able to login again.

Answer (score 0):

Disable clean URLs. Configure your server / drupal for clean URLs, then enable clean URLs.
How to configure clean url on an server depend on kind of server setup you are running.More info on clean urls http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Comment: I am running MAMP server,I can't login so I'm unclear how to disable clean urls

Comment: ok i got them turned off in drupal by turning them off on my original site and then recopying the db over but now when I try to enable the clean url test fails I suspect it due to virtual host

Comment: double check your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by either removing the entries in the flood table (as stated by user8012) or installing a module to assist with removing the entries. Please read [http://bri-space.com/content/how-fix-drupal-7-blocked-account-after-5-incorrect-password-attempts](http://web.archive.org/web/20180128220929/http://bri-space.com:80/content/how-fix-drupal-7-blocked-account-after-5-incorrect-password-attempts) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpMyAdmin to delete the entries in the "flood" table.

1. Go to your phpMyAdmin page and login
2. Select the database of your Drupal website from the left sidebar
3. Click on the "SQL" link on the top horizontal menu
4. Copy the following SQL query:

   ```
   DELETE FROM flood;
   ```

   paste it in the text area of the "SQL" page and click on the "Go" button.
5. The entries in the "flood" table will be deleted and you will now be able to login to your Drupal website.

OR

You can use terminal.

1. Connect to your server with ssh

   ```
   ssh root@URLofYourWebsite.com
   ```

   alternatively you can use the IP address of your website

   ```
   ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   ```
2. Start the MySQL prompt by typing

   ```
   mysql -uroot -p
   ```

   and give your password.
3. Select the database that you want to use

   ```
   USE yourDatabaseName;
   ```
4. And delete the entries from the "flood" table

   ```
   DELETE FROM flood;
   ```
5. Exit from MySQL and from the server and now you'll be able to login again.

   ```
   exit;
   ```